# Select2 not working for dynamically added fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Hi I am trying to add dropdown field to my form dynamically and applying it select2 dropdown plugin. My code is as follow:

```
TDList.eq(1).html("<input type='text' class='InsideTDSelect'></input>");
```

this will add text field inside table td. I already defined json array like this

```
var sampleArray = [{id:0,text:'enhancement'}, {id:1,text:'bug'}
                   ,{id:2,text:'duplicate'},{id:3,text:'invalid'}
                   ,{id:4,text:'wontfix'}];
```

and binding it to newly created field as below

```
$(".InsideTDSelect").select2({ data: sampleArray });
```

but it's not working. Why it's not working

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize it after putting in the dom, i mean to say the you should put in the callback function of the `.html()`:

```
TDList.eq(1).html("<input type='text' class='InsideTDSelect' />", function(){
    $(".InsideTDSelect").select2({ data: sampleArray });
});
```